# frequently appended transient closure

Tags: c++, graph, mathematical-optimization, connectivity, array-algorithms

I have a large multi-map of pairs (c++), which I use to do the connectivity analysis. Since Warshall algorithm is O(N**3), with the large N, I am converting the multi-map registered pairs to a bool matrix and apply Warshall to that matrix. 
Unfortunately, my collection of pairs is a subject to frequent additions (no removal), and after adding new pairs, the connectivity might be subjected to significant changes. It works, but the performance is an issue, especially when N becomes large. Can someone with the expertise in the area suggest an efficient and reliable algorithm for updating the closure matrix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say look outside. Graphs basically run the world, so there are some existing libraries like [SNAP](https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/) that claim to build large efficient graphs. Also, [Boost Graphs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/boost/graph/floyd_warshall_shortest.hpp) appears to have a Warshall's implementation if you haven't already considered it.

Comment: This feels like a homework or competitive programming problem.  Try [union-find disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).